# What is the fastest way to get my alexa to read a web page?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, ifttt

I want Alexa to point to a url like [www.website.com/stockprice.php](http://www.website.com/stockprice.php) and I want to ask alexa, what is the stock price and alexa should read a string that will be available at that location. What is the easiest way to get this done. I do have IFTTT

Comment: The thing you are asking would require web scraping fairly easy to accomplish in a number of languages, a targeted site where you have identified the information to be retrieved from, and lastly a function to convert the scraped data into text to be replayed as TTS. I'm not sure that IFTTT is your answer, a quick review of github, I found at least one python solution to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two ways this can be done (based on how generic you want the solution to be). In both approach you will need to create a Alexa skill. To make the triggering of skill smooth you can look at [NFI](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/understand-name-free-interaction-for-custom-skills.html)

Approach 1 : Load and parse website to find the content
This approach will work if you have only 1 web page and you are aware of the page structure. Once control comes to your Skill lambda, you can add logic to fetch the web page and search for the specific tag.

Approach 2: Plug skill with a Question Answering system
This approach can be used if you have large number of websites in the corpus and you want to be able to answer any questions on the content. In this case, you can ingest the websites using AWS Kendra. You can then plug your skill to Kendra to answer questions.